# Is it possible to use PLSQL to decode the dataURL generated by canvas.toDataURL()?

Tags: plsql, html5-canvas, base64, oracle-apex, html2canvas

If possible, how can I post this dataURL from front end to back end?

My demand:
1. use html2canvas to capture the current window
2. convert html5 canvas object into data URL
3. send the data URL to the server side
4. PLSQL decode the data URL then download it as an image file

I knew this feature can be finished by using other language, but I have to use Oracle APEX(PLSQL) to finish it.

So if someone knows how to finish it, please provide some hints or ideas. Example will be better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why wont you upload the image itself as a blob?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to finish that feature by using a Plug-in created by Dani3lSun. Thanks for Dani3lSun. The link for the demo and source code:https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-apexscreencapture